# Python request.post while also using proxy - not working

Tags: python, urllib2, python-requests

I am having an issue with the below code where when I try to post my login/pw to access the actual page I want to end up at, I time out with 10060.  However, if I comment out the `post`, I do get a response, however it is the log-in page (since obviously I am then trying to access `url` without logging in).

I have done this on a diff network that did not require proxy without issue, using the same payload.  Something to do with the combo of proxy/post is causing an issue, and I'm not sure what it is.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://site/stuff_i_want"

payload = {
    'login':'login_name',
    'Password':'pw'
}

proxies={'http': 'http://domain\login:pw@proxy_ip:port',
         'https': 'http://domain\login:pw@proxy_ip:port'
    }

with requests.session() as s:
    p = s.post('https://site/login', data=payload) #w/o post the login page loads, with post I time-out.
    r = s.get(url,proxies=proxies)
    print r.content
```

Comment: Does your post to the site's login also need to go via the proxies?

Comment: I am an idiot. I added `proxies=proxies` to the `post` and it is working.

Comment: was just about to suggest that haha.